# SVN preview update showing conflicts but update doesn't result in conflict

Tags: svn, version-control, merge

We are seeing an odd issue in our repo where the following command reports incoming conflicts:

```
svn merge --dry-run -r BASE:HEAD . | egrep -e '^[[:space:]]*(A|B|C|D|E|G|U)+[[:space:]]+'

   C path/to/fileA
   C path/to/fileB
   C path/to/fileC
U    path/to/fileD
```

However, an svn up does not actually result in a conflict.  In fact, the output looks like this:

```
At revision 7922.
At revision 7922.
At revision 7922.
U    path/to/fileD
Updated to revision 7922.
```

As far as I can tell, there is nothing odd about the files in question.  An svn status does not report any issues, svn info shows that the files are up to date, and svn resolve has no effect.  This is happening periodically but not every time, and it's always the same files that show up.

Has anyone seen this before?

**Edit**: It looks like I left out a crucial detail, which is perhaps why no one has been able to answer here.  During the svn up step, we're updating each file individually to avoid collisions during a graduated automatic deployment (e.g. t0: look ahead for incoming updates, t1: run any necessary schema changes against the database, t1+X: update the rest of the batch, where X could be a non-trivial number).  The full update looks like this:

```
svn up --depth=empty path/to/fileA path/to/fileB path/to/fileC path/to/fileD

At revision 7922.
At revision 7922.
At revision 7922.
U    path/to/fileD
Updated to revision 7922.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the issue here is coming from parent directories which are out of sync.

Ex:

Revision X:

```
A  path/to/fileA
```

Revision X+1:

```
A  path/to/fileB
A  path/to/fileC
```

We had been updating like so: (let's assume BASE = X-1 and HEAD = X+1)

```
%> cd dir/
%> svn merge --dry-run -r BASE:HEAD .     # look ahead for incoming updates
%> ...                                    # run schema updates against DB
%> svn up --depth=empty path/to/fileA     # update just the incoming changes to
   path/to/fileB path/to/fileC            # avoid pulling someone else's
                                          # recent commit
```

While this is all well and good for the 3 files involved in the commit, dir/, dir/path/, and dir/path/to/ are now behind the HEAD revision.  svn info dir/ reports the revision as X-1 (BASE), because it wasn't included in the previous svn up.

Now when we get to Revision X+2:

```
U  path/to/fileD
```

We try the process again, but this time the look-ahead reports conflicts:

```
%> cd dir/
%> svn merge --dry-run -r BASE:HEAD .
...
   C path/to/fileA
   C path/to/fileB
   C path/to/fileC
U    path/to/fileD
...
```

(Incoming adds from X-1->X+2, when really the files are already there).  At the same time, an svn up on those files will harmlessly report everything is up to date.

We have since turned our deployment into a more atomic process, so we're free to svn up everything from the branch root, avoid the ugly --depth=empty, and keep all files in sync.